# Mysql init.d to systemd

Tags: scripting, systemd, mysql, startup

I have two mysql instances on a centos 7 machine. init.d handles start on boot. problem is, only one instance starts on boot. both instances uses two different ports. Can someone help me with how to transfer those instances to be controlled by systemd. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This article, [How to create multiple mysql instance in CentOS 6.4](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/12/02/create-multiple-mysql-instance-centos-6-4-red-hat-6-4/), should work for Centos 7.